# Mapping arrays reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have two tables namely table1 and table2.

table 1 fields are table1Id, name
table 2 fields are table2Id, table1Id

I have a multiple array:

```
const [arr1, setarr1] = useState([]);
const [arr2, setarr2] = useState([]);
```

I need to map the two arrays.

```
{arr2.map()......} return(
      {arr2.name}
)
```

How can I get the name field from my first table to my second table?

Expected input

```
Table1
id: 1
name: MyTable

Table2
Table2Id: 1
Table1Id: 1
```

Expected Output:

MyTable

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample input and an expected output?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

#### Filter your `array` to get every match with a specific `id`

```
function getNames(id) {
  return arr1
           .filter(item => item.id === id)
           .map(item => item.name);
}
```

#### Usage

```
arr2
  .map(item => getNames(item.table1Id))
  .reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next));
```

#### Output

```
["MyTable"]
```

I'm still not sure if this is what you were looking for, but let me know if I got that **wrong**. I'm happy to help.

Comment: Yeah, I already figured it out before seeing your answer. But will tagged this as the answer! Thank you!!